# ASB Logcat and while shell loop. How can I output to file on a regular basis?

Tags: macos, shell, adb

```
while true; 
  do 
    adb logcat -v time | grep "thepid" > Log.`date +%Y`.`date +%m`.`date +%d`-`date +%H`.`date +%M`.`date +%S`.txt; 
    sleep 10; 
    adb shell screencap -p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > ScreenCap.`date +%Y`.`date +%m`.`date +%d`-`date +%H`.`date +%M`.`date +%S`.png; 
  done
```

This is supposed to write to a timestamped log. Wait 10 seconds. Take a screenshot and save that to a timestamped png.

However, all parts work on their own but don't work together.

Any help is welcome at this point in the day.

Comment: 12 `date` calls just to get the date? ouch... how about `date +%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S`?

Comment: as for your question, just add `-d` to your logcat command

Comment: so the solution might be adb logcat -d -v time ....?

Comment: What is the meaning of 'don't work'?